# every gluing by homeomorphisms on the boundry of to 3-balls gives the 3 sphere

Tags: general-topology

Is there an "easy" (meaning understandable with  2 courses in topology ) proof, why every gluing by homeomorphisms on the boundry  of to 3-balls gives the 3 sphere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the fact that every orientation preserving homeomorphism of the $2$-sphere is isotopic to the identity. I.e. the mapping class group of a 2-sphere is trivial. [This blog post](https://rigtriv.wordpress.com/2015/01/14/the-mapping-class-group/) has a hint as to how to prove this. You need to use [Alexander's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander%27s_trick) and the Jordan curve theorem.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider it in the other direction. The 3 sphere minus the north pole $S^3\setminus \{(0,0,0,1)\}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^4~:~|x|=1,~x_4<1\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$ using the stereographic projection. And $\mathbb{R}^3$ is homeomorphic to the open 3 ball $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3~:~|x|<1\}$. The boundary of the 3 ball is the north pole of your 3 sphere, since each sequence on the open 3 ball, which converge to a point in the boundary, goes on the 3 sphere to the north pole.

Maybe it is more plausible if you draw a sketch for the case of the 2 sphere and 2 ball.

This is no complete proof, but I'm sure you can use this idea to get a proof.

Comment: This shows that one particular homeomorphism of the 2-sphere to itself gives a $3$-sphere, but the issue is to show that every such homeomorphism does, which is a bit trickier.